# Pandas/SQL-calculate the pecentage based on different Group

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I want to calculate the percentage of each group and a new column
For example:
data=

```
Group  Value   
  A     1
  A     2
  A     1
  B     4
  B     4
  B     8
```

and I want to get:

```
Group  Value   Percentage
  A     1         0.25
  A     2         0.50
  A     1         0.25
  B     4         0.25
  B     4         0.25
  B     8         0.50
```

How to get it with pandas function or SQL? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pandas:

```
df['Percentage'] = df.groupby('Group')['Value'].transform(lambda x: x / x.sum())
```

output:

```
  Group  Value  Percentage
0     A      1        0.25
1     A      2        0.50
2     A      1        0.25
3     B      4        0.25
4     B      4        0.25
5     B      8        0.50
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
SELECT A.Group, 
       A.Value, 
       ( A.Value / (SELECT Sum(b.Value) 
                    FROM   yourtable b 
                    WHERE  b.Group = A.Group) ) Percentage
FROM   yourtable A
```